# spark-shell and sparkR in Google DataProc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am very new to Google DataProc

We want to run set of code via spark-shell or sparkR for testing purposes. 
Is it possible to connect to spark cluster and execute the commands in spark-shell or sparkR in google DataProc?

I checked the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/submit-job) and it seems we can submit jobs using spark-submit but I don't find information related to spark-shell or SparkR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

spark-shell and sparkR are installed on all VMs in the dataproc cluster and you can SSH into any of them (I usually use the master node) and run spark-shell or sparkR.